# Javascript and Jquery issue

Tags: javascript

Hello I am using a zoom plugin called cloudzoom on a weebly website, it was working partially and now it has stopped working.

http://cadogan.weebly.com/big-name.html

I add jquery no conflict etc. But, I think I have something wrong on the page regarding how I loaded the cloud zoom possibly.
Assitance will be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: thee problem is that it stopped working

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem using jquery in weebly sites, I resolved it with this three steps.

a) Try copy and pasting the raw jQuery file onto the page. between the   markup

b) use jQuery.noConflict(); after the jquery call

c) change the "$()" for "jquery()" when you call the custom function.

I hope it helps you.

regards,

William Hernández
www.floopie.net

Comment: William, Thank you for the recommendation but now it isn't working at all I think I am doing something wrong if you have the time can you look at the source file.